# * is being replaced by current folders file list

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am performing a grep on a file which is resulting in a single line output. This output has * as data in it. In the shell script I am trying to assign the value to a variable but * is being replaced with the file list in the current folder.

Eg:
My script name is `script1.sh` and I have another file `script2.sh` in the same directory.

The content of the script is

```
VAR1=`grep pattern search_file`
echo $VAR1
```

The intended output would be

> The pattern is *

But the output I am getting is

> The pattern is script1.sh script2.sh

Kindly let me know what is that I am doing wrong.

Comment: I tried this in the prompt.
VAR=`echo "*"`
echo $VAR resulted in the same issue as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `set -f` shell option will disable globbing in sub-shells and interactive session.
use `set +f` to enable globbing again.

Comment: This is like shutting off your water main because you have a leaky faucet. Effective, but overly broad.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to quote the variable: `echo "$VAR1"`

If you look at the sequence of [bash shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions), you'll notice that filename expansion occurs *after* parameter expansion. **Unquoted** variables will be subsequently subjected to word splitting and filename expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the * with \, otherwise it treats it as a wild-card that matches filenames in the current directory.

```
\*
```

Comment: There's less of an opportunity to escape the `*`, since it's being read from a file via `grep`.